# With Git, is it possible to download a revision without cloning the repo?

Tags: git

Basically, I'd like to download the working tree at a particular revision without cloning anything. In particular, I don't want any .git directory in the resulting download. Another way to think of what I'm asking for is the converse of a bare repo: a bare working tree.

The use case is pretty straightforward, when you simply want to use the code or data without any intention of modifying it or playing with history.

I know of `git clone --depth 1`, but in my experience the cloned repo is still twice as big as the working tree alone.

Comment: You can use [`git archive`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) with the `--remote` option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git archive` can do the job

try : `git archive -vvv --remote=<REPO_URL> -o output.zip <REF>`

Please note: `REF` should be only a named ref - branch, tag, etc. It does not allow you to pick certain commit.

**update**

Download and extract oneliner

`$ git archive -vvv --remote=<REPO_URL> -o archive.tar <REF> && tar -xvvf archive.tar && rm archive.tar`

**update 2**

Better oneliner

`$ git archive -vvv --remote=<REPO_URL> <REF> | tar -xvf -`

You may use `--prefix` flag of `git archive` to add prefix dir or you may refer to `tar` docs to extract contents into other directory.

For example

`$ git archive -vvv --prefix=stack/ --remote=<REPO_URL> <REF> | tar -xvf -`
will extract contents of repo into `stack` directory.

Comment: Could it by any chance output to a directory instead of a zip file?

Comment: @static_rtti, no by default, but I found the following example in `git help archive`: 
`git archive --format=tar --prefix=junk/ HEAD | (cd /var/tmp/ && tar xf -)
           Create a tar archive that contains the contents of the latest commit on the current branch, and extract it in the /var/tmp/junk directory.`
Please check out this article http://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive 'EXAMPLES' section. You may find some useful tips.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm sure this will prove useful to many people.